# Filling squares by sequential numbers

Tags: calculus

I need to fill a grid NxN by sequential numbers, like this

```
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
48 09 10 11 12 13 32
47 24 01 02 03 14 33
46 23 08 00 04 15 34
45 22 07 06 05 16 35
44 21 20 19 18 17 36
43 42 41 40 39 38 37
```

starting from center and filling squares clockwise.
So there are squares, which have numbers on their perimeters

Square #0 for number 0
Square #1 for numbers 1 till 8
Square #2 for numbers 9 till 24
Square #3 for numbers 25 till 48
and so on.

Can you suggest **formula** to get # of square, which have a given number?
So, for example, it will give square #1 for 4, square #2 for 19, square #3 for 33, etc.

Comment: Can you give the formula when $n$ is a  square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left\lfloor\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor+1\over2 \right\rfloor$$

should do the trick

Comment: Wrong :( It gives, for example, #4 for 19, but should #2.

Comment: @Alexey, the integer part of $\sqrt{19}$ is $4$, and the integer part of $4+1\over2$ is $2$.

Comment: Ooops, you are right! My bet, had checked it in Excel and mistaken in formula.